# Android Eclipse won't start. An error has occurred. see the log file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-adt

I know that this question has been asked several times on StackOverflow (and others), but none of the solutions I've found works for me.

As you can see in the headline I am getting the following error message, when starting Android eclipse:

> an error has occurred. see the log file

I have tried removing SNAP files and Vmargs directive from the eclipse.ini file. I've also tried to clean Eclipse with the command:

> PATH/TO/ECLIPSE -clean

But with no result.

I am running the ADT Eclipse bundle on Windows 7.

And here is what my log file says (repeatedly) when I try to run it:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2014-05-26 13:45:14.494 !MESSAGE
>   Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
>   "org.eclipse.core.resources". !STACK 0 java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.activities.WorkbenchActivityHelper.isFiltering(WorkbenchActivityHelper.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchActivityHelper$3.resourceChanged(IDEWorkbenchActivityHelper.java:158)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1530)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

And this is what it wrote out as the last thing when/before I closed eclipse last time:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-05-25 21:37:47.323
!MESSAGE An unexpected exception was thrown.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.updateActiveShell(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:924)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.getCurrentState(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider$6.handleEvent(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4525)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1217)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.open(InternalDialog.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$3.show(JFaceUtil.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.handleException(SafeRunnable.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.fireWindowClosed(Workbench.java:948)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.fireWindowClosed(WorkbenchWindow.java:1255)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$14(WorkbenchWindow.java:1136)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$10.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:1195)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$6.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer$11.shellClosed(WBWRenderer.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(Decorations.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_CLOSE(Decorations.java:1694)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4530)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
!SESSION 2014-05-26 13:23:08.484 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
```

I really hope some of you can help me fix this.
The last time I closed Android eclipse, some problems occured because it was out of memory. I don't why this suddenly happened.

Comment: Java version could be an issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course, just after posting the question, I've found the solution.

If others run into the same problem, try deleting the following folder from your workspace:

```
C:\.. \workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench
```

Comment: I don't have such a folder :(