# Eclipse does not start. An error has occured. See the log file. C:\path_to_eclipse\configuration\1429818588469.log

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I went through this link
[An error has occured. Please see log file - eclipse juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno) and this link too
[Android Eclipse won't start. An error has occurred. see the log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869849/android-eclipse-wont-start-an-error-has-occurred-see-the-log-file). I tried all the answers suggested here but none of them worked for me. I could not find the .snap file so I ended up deleting the entire workspace. Please let me know if someone has ran into same issue.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you actually tried looking at the log file? If so, please copy and paste any relevant information.

Comment: its a big log file. i can give you the main headings java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display. 
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError.
Hope this makes some sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> and kill the Java process. Then restart eclipse again.